# GIS applications and noSQL solutions

Tags: geoserver, plugins, openlayers-2, mongodb

I'm a bit lost about NoSQL and applications using GIS.

My aim, to sum it up quickly, is to store geospatial object into a MongoDB database and display them into a map via OpenLayers. 
Is it possible to retrieve geospatial data directly from MongoDB and display them into OpenLayers after someone requested it into the application, or have I to use inevitably a server than can handle geospatial data like GeoServer ?

It seems that MongoDB and GeoServer are quite hard to plug, and even if I found a driver it needs further development and I have no time.

If you have some examples, I'll be glad to take a look.
Or If you have some documentation for the driver mentioned above, I'll be glad too :-).

Comment: GeoServer +MongoDB Slideshare http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongo-db-dc2013mongogeoserverfinal

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I already know this slidershare presentation, it was the start of my reflexion. But it doesn't provide help on how to use the plug-in and unfortunately I did not find any documentation anywhere. I even tried to send an email to the authors of this presentation but they never answered back :(

Comment: see: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/MongoDB-plugin-td5042018.html sounds like you need to find another solution.

Comment: You could store GeoJSON directly in MongoDB and then deliver them over the web through a lightweight API like [Bottle (for Python)](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [Express (for Node.js)](http://expressjs.com/). If you are unable to deploy a web server like one of these, you could try [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) instead, store GeoJSON documents, and access them using CouchDB's native REST API. By comparison, MongoDB has at least some spatial filtering awareness.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. If I sum up, I could do an architecture like that : MongoDB > Node.js > OpenLayers ? Or OpenLayers would be within Node.js ? Sorry I'm a bit lost into all I can read on the internet :'(

Comment: Anyway I think this is the way I'll go because it would be too hard to handle in a short time. I'll update there after my PoC is done to tell you which way I chose and if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the question was asked a bit ago here is one solution:

Have a look at the status page of your Geoserver-GUI and see which Geotools version your geoserver uses:

[image]

Then download the gt-mongodb-jar of the version xx from

http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/geotools/gt-mongodb

--> in my case version 11

http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/geotools/gt-mongodb/11.0/gt-mongodb-11.0.jar

Put this file in your Geoserver-lib-folder, for example
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib

Do the same with the MongoDB-Java-Driver which you get here:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/

( I took the version 2.12 as it was released roughly at the same time the version 11.0 of the gt-mongodb-file was released. I haven't tested if newer versions would work too. )

Restart Tomcat and you should see a MongoDB-Store in your Geoserver-Installation:
[image]

Comment: Hey, it's never too late to answer a question in SO :). Fortunately I was able to make this work a year ago (with some modifications needed in the JAR though).